# Ignoring certain files and changes in capistrano's current directory for development environment

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano, development-environment, environment

Our deploy strategy: We have environment-scoped db config and `.htaccess` files (think `prod.htaccess`, `dev.htaccess` and `local.htaccess`). Deploys are done using capistrano, which starts with a checkout of the branch to be deployed, then deletes `Capfile` and out-of-scope `.htaccess` files and renames the in-scope htaccess from `[env].htaccess` to `.htaccess`. This complete, the `repository/public_html` directory is transferred via non-deleting rsync to the apache webroot.

> Background: The company I work for is an online publication that's
>   been around since 1998 and the deploy strategy is convoluted because
>   the folder structure is a mess: version-controlled files live next to
>   generated files and user-uploaded files. This being the case, we can't
>   just symlink the entire apache webroot folder to the corresponding
>   folder in `/current`. Generated files would be wiped out on each time
>   a new deploy is made, the user uploaded files scattered about the
>   directories would have to be symlinked in from other places, etc. Thus
>   the non-deleting rsync operation.

The current insanity alluded to above is a question for another day, though.

What I want is a solution that doesn't require the deleting and renaming of htaccess and db config files in the repo upon deploy. The reason is so that we can work in and commit from `/deploy/current` without having to contend with the tangle of local changes from the deploy.

What are the typical solutions for deployment of environment-scoped files like this? Should I move them to a `/config` folder above `/public_html` and symlink from apache webroot to the relevant files in `/config` depending on environment?

Comment: It sounds like your `[env].htaccess` files shouldn't be kept inside of the repository. Why not put them in your `shared` folder and symlink to the appropriate one on deployment?

Comment: Do you need the developers / sysops to work on the .htaccess files together at the same time? If yes then for how long? I have one idea but do not know if it will suite your needs.

Comment: @cdesrosiers if not inside the repository, then how to share changes to the files? Do you mean have capistrano delete them from `/current` on deploy, instead symlinking from `.htaccess` in `/current` to `[env].htaccess` within /shared?

Comment: @Jeznet yes, it's not uncommon to add a new line in `prod.htaccess` that will also need to be added to `local.htaccess` and `dev.htaccess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to approach this in the following way:

- Still keep all your `[env].htaccess` files in the repository.
- After `deploy:update` symlink all of your `[env].htaccess` files to `.htaccess`
  symlinks (`ln --symbolic [env].htaccess .htaccess`)
- Do not delete the `*.htaccess` files.
- Let the developers / sysops edit the `*.htaccess` files (they will have access to the in scope files via the `.htaccess` symlink and to all of the out of scope [env].htaccess files to.
- Let the developers / sysops commit right from the `deploy/current` folder (but be sure that it is valid repository from which you can commit.).
- Use this process for other types of files you work with.

I think this might solve the problem you described or at least ease it. I would personally start doing this like that and see how it will work out.

BTW Why do you delete the `Capfile` after `deploy:update`?

Comment: Thanks! The reason for the Capfile deletion is a bit involved. The company I work for is an online publication that's been around since 1998. The folder structure is a mess: version-controlled files live next to generated files and user-uploaded files. This being the case, we can't just symlink the entire folder to the corresponding folder in /current. Rather, we do a non-deleting rsync from public_html in the repo to apache's webroot. The Capfile is deleted before the rsync operation executes. We could just exclude the file from the rsync operation though.

Comment: The idea is to symlink new folders in and slowly clean up mixed folders so we can symlink them in.

Comment: So the workflow would be to exclude `*.htaccess` from the rsync and symlink `[env].htaccess]` to `.htaccess`.

Comment: What happens with a folder like /system/config/that *is* symlinked in to current, but contains `database.local.php`, `database.dev.php`, `database.prod.php`. Add a special case rule to avoid symlinking the folder, and instead symlink to the individual correctly scoped file?

Comment: I guess this whole thing seems rather convoluted and inelegant. Are there better solutions out there?

Comment: @kayaker243 If you expect a good answer you must provide a good detailed question. Please describe *in detail*, step by step, what you do now, what are your requirements, or at least what is not fine with my answer?